# How to make visible only a portion of an object during playback?

Tags: animation

I have a mesh that necessarily contains many many vertices, which inevitably slows down animation playback. But, I only want to view parts of the mesh at a time, yet in the outliner, there is no visibility toggle on the vertex groups to save users processing time. Is there some other way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Mask constraint on the mesh will work to improve the frame rate during playback. You have to create a vertex group for each part you want to view at a time, but once you do, you simply set that as the target vertex group in the mask constraint, or also press arrow button if it looks the reverse of your vertex group is showing up.